# Is article and auxiliary verb omission in modern English an emerging phenomenon?

Tags: grammar, articles, auxiliary-verbs, language-change, conversational-deletion

***I am obviously not talking about newspaper headlines etc. in this question.***

I tried looking it up online but wasn't able to find much. In many instances of spoken English (and, probably, making its way into written English as well), I notice people omit articles where they grammatically shouldn't.

An example from Daredevil which I just watched and remembered I've had this question for a while: "**Kid**'s half an idiot! – It's the other half that counts." I'm positive you know what I'm getting at here. One could say "**Dude** is built like a tank" when the dude in question has been addressed already (and technically should have a "the" preceding it).
I have an intuition that the longer the phrase is, the less natural the omission sounds. For example, it's harder for me to imagine a phrase like "Dude flipped the table like it was made out of carton" without wanting to slap a "the" at the beginning.

I swear I've heard someone say "**less** you know about this, the better."

And finally, something that is probably the most widespread: dropping auxiliary verbs. It is so normal to ask a question like "**sleep** well?", meaning "did you sleep well?".

Yet, I cannot find any articles on this topic, and sometimes it makes me question whether I'm mishearing things. Yet, it is so widespread, there is no doubt it is a real phenomenon.

Is it a new phenomenon? Has anything like this happened before, either in English or in other languages? Are there any particular rules governing it?

**Notes**:

- As of January 4, 2018, it is not listed as a type of grammatical ellipsis on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)#Types_of_ellipsis).
- It is not an example of [Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).
- Questions like [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26218/in-which-situations-is-it-ok-to-omit-articles-in-short-sentences) boil down to variations of headlinese / computerspeak, which is, again, not the case.
- [Examples of archaic and/or poetic usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297596/when-is-dropping-the-definite-or-indefinite-article-permissible-and-why) may not be relevant here, but it would be delightful if there are parallels.

Comment: See John Lawler's answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/24489).

Comment: Thank you! For some reason it was not showing up on my searches, and even now it is not listed as "Related."  
I closed the question by marking it as a duplicate.